# Java generics versus C++ templates

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics

I think I can sum up the use of generics in Java in one word: type-safety.
Can you conclude the use of templates in C++ in one word, please?

Comment: That's about like asking that somebody summarize the uses for water (or air) in a single word.

Comment: People with higher rep... vote to close? I'm pretty sure this counts as "bad subjective"

Comment: I was under the impression that generics were about generic programming, not type safety.  Type safety is a feature of the implementation they have of generic programming.  `object` is the previous (and entrenched) implementation.

Comment: @Merlyn, I would argue that type-safety is in fact a better one-word description that gets to the heart of Java generics.  Java always had generic programming abilities, since any function that takes an `Object` is essentially generic.  Let's be honest, generics were added because people were sick of having to cast `Object` to the correct type.

Comment: @Charles: We're on the same page here, but I feel like being a language lawyer, since the question is directly about language :)  "sum up the *use* of generics", not "sum up the reason *why* feature x was introduced to the language".  You use it to do generic programming.  The semantics are important, because some people using `object` or generics don't understand that they might (or might not) be doing generic programming, and might (or might not) be shooting themselves in the foot by using the wrong tool for the job :)

Comment: Java's generics implementation falls short of giving you solid type-safety since it is done using erasure (compiler inserted casts).  You can, for example, pass a List of Integer as an argument to a function taking a plain old List and add a String to it without any compiler warnings or errors.

Comment: Agree with Dragontamer.  Not because it's subjective(though it certainly is).  Rather because it has less to do with Programming than with English.

Comment: Doesn't "type-safety" sum up C++ templates just as well?

Comment: @UncleBens no - type safety is one of many features facilitated by C++ templates.

Comment: @UncleBens, Michael E: It sums it up for templates just as well as it does generics.  Which is to say, not well at all :)  See my comment above.

Comment: "type safety" is two words...

Answer (score 5):

One word: **Meta-programming**.

But really, what you're asking is very difficult.  Templates are a complex topic.  At heart, templates are facilities for meta-programming: that is, they're code which generates more code.

In the real world, templates are *used* most often to generate multiple classes or functions from the same class/function template, each of which is used with different type parameters.  In other words, generic-programming.  This is probably best showcased by the container classes in the STL.

But because templates are ultimately a meta-programming facility, they do more than just allow you to implement generic classes/functions.  Specialization, partial specialization, and [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE) allows for a whole range of code-generation abilities that goes well beyond implementing generic classes or functions.  In fact, recursive template instantiation allows you to program using a Turing-complete meta-language embedded within C++.

Answer (score 3):

One word: **suffering**

Comment: Or how about, three words: indecipherable compiler errors

Answer (score 2):

C++ Templates: code generators. (two words)

Comment: @Stephen: hehehehehehehehe... G1!

Answer (score 1):

Since hyphens are evidently allowed, 'generic-programming'.  Note that 'generic' in this context does not have quite the same meaning as it does in Java generics.  Java generics are really a different name for parametric polymorphism; the generic programming facilitated by C++ templates goes beyond what is allowed by parametric polymorphism.

Comment: If you have to explain what you mean by your word, it's no longer one word, is it? ;)  Not that I think describing something like this in one word would be useful to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

c++ templates: templates.  Its tautological, but since we are restricted to one word, Templates is as complete a one I can think of...

Answer (score 0):

I found the word: type-independence.
what do you think of that?